# Internet Explorer css issues: border-radius, background-color, gradient

Tags: internet-explorer, background-color, css

I am having trouble figuring out what changes need to be made for this page to display correctly in internet explorer. I have tried the usual fixes: define browser standards, added a clearing div, added a height, used 'background' instead of 'background-color', but nothing changes. The background stays transparent.

I need the `#main` div background to be white. Not as important, but also needed, I'm not sure why border-radius isn't display either.

There is a section of the site that you have to log in to see, but that also is having a problem. I'm using the css gradient, and I thought I was using all of the needed options for cross-broswer displaying, but the buttons do not have a background gradient. This is what I am using for the gradient:

```
background: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(0,0,0) 0%, rgb(102,51,102) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(0,0,0) 0%, rgb(102,51,102) 100%);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(0,0,0) 0%, rgb(102,51,102) 100%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(0,0,0) 0%, rgb(102,51,102) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(0,0,0) 0%, rgb(102,51,102) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, rgb(0,0,0)), color-stop(1, rgb(102,51,102)));
```

That's also not immediately a problem because I have a backup background color, but oddly enough, the border radius on these buttons works fine.

I'm not having any other IE issues, but if there are any others that you see, I am open.

The website is http://connectroot.com

Comment: What version of IE? IE9 and lower don't support some of these. I suggest doing a quick Google search with `browser support rule`. There are workarounds, and safe fallback to throw to IE, like a background image for gradient, filter (slow and not recommended), or simply a flat color. There are also polyfills available for these if they are really necessary (like css3pie). Google your rule + polyfill

Comment: I'm just starting with ie10 for now. The site needs a separate style sheet for ie8 and lower anyway. From what I've read, it seems like ie10 should be supporting some of these. The document standard is ie9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the missing background is the parent not expanding to its content. Simply floating it gets it to come back, but it might not the best solution (I haven't extensively checked your layout). The rounded corners in the navigation are hidden behind a back background nav.main-navigation (style comes from nav).

Right now Webkit browsers gives rounded corners to elements inside (nav being inside #main), but IE doesn't. A cleaner approach would be to have your nav outside #main :

```
<nav>    <-- rounded corner, black bg
<main>   <-- white bg
```

I cannot find the gradient. I hope this helps a bit, IE dev tools are a pain :(